# Anaconda installed but can't launch Navigator in Window 10

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on my Dell laptop. I am able to use anaconda promt but unable to launch anaconda-navigator.
I tried it launching via icon, command line. It shows anaconda icon with Initializing message on it and then disappears.
I tried launching it via command promt with admin privilege. It opened and then disappeared in a few seconds.
No error comes on screen.
I searched for different solutions on Github and stack overflow but nothing worked.
Check it in following images.

[checking everything is up to date or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4GYd.jpg)

[launched anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTjCu.png)

[disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHeYY.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can reinstall anaconda on your machine because any file missing then happened and Anaconda prompt into you can try below command.

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: I am able to launch jupyter from conda promt and able to use R and Python. Just not able to use navigator.